# How do I write a binary file in a Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to implement a StreamSocket communication and the server is now sending me a ".zip" file in byte[] chuncks. It looks like my byte[] in memory is fine (amount of bytes are the same as original .zip file in the server) but when I save those bytes in a file the unzip program says it's 'corrupted'.

I've tried several options but none of them worked for me:

1

```
var file = await StorageFile.CreateFileAsync();
using(var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    stream.Write(myBytes, ...);
}
```

2

```
var file = await StorageFile.CreateFileAsync();
await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, myBytes);
```

3

```
var file = await StorageFile.CreateFileAsync();
using (var fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    var sessionData = new MemoryStream(myBytes);
    sessionData.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    await sessionData.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}
```

4

```
var file = await StorageFile.CreateFileAsync();
using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    writer.WriteBytes(myBytes);
}
```

If anyone has some new ideas please share.

Regards.

Comment: What does "none of them worked for me" mean?  What error did you receive, what did you expect?

Comment: All of the options created a file with the bytes inside (1MB size) but then the file turns to be corrupted when I try to unzip.

Comment: Well, have you opened the result in a hex editor?  Are certain bytes not being stored correctly, or is there an extra header on the file created via `StorageFile`, or something else?  **Exactly what is wrong with the file your application created?**  From the information you've given us so far "unzip program says file isn't valid" you might be getting bogus data from the server.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Only a few seconds before you comment I realised I hadn't made any hex comparisson. I'll make some updates when that's done.

Comment: Ok.. so I compared both files and they were different. After some time reviewing the whole protocol, I discovered that server expected an offset to start sending the file and I had been sending the size of the last received file, so the first part of my .zip file was never been sent.
Now, fixed that, I tried saving the file using the first option I was using and it worked fine. I don't know how I should close this question, as the question has the answer.

Comment: @LautaroRodriguezGarrido I would formulate your own answer explaining in details what was your problem, how you solved it, etc. Then when it allows you accept your answer. This way people looking on how to write binary files in Windows Store Apps will have a quick answer when stumbling on your post

Comment: Great! I'll be waiting for it. Thanks!